# Added indentation shows as new code while reviewing

Tags: support, bug, review, code-formatting

While reviewing a post on SO, I came across something as following:

[image: Suggested Edit 3654944]

Everything that's done here is just removal of indentations but the lines are showed as new lines. Can we just highlight the removed spaces in red in the old copy of the post?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is needed because the requested feature is already covered under the **markdown diff** option. Screenshot for a quick reference:

[image: Markdown view]

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this suggested edit? I have a bit of doubt about change #1 here.

Comment: grgarside provided the link in the question, @Rachcha. FWIW, I tend to review with the Markdown diff turned on by default; it's *usually* a lot easier to see what has changed that way.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging- Sure it is; the problem here is that a few spaces added or removed are showed as a new line. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging why isn't this a feature request? He's asking to change current behavior of the diff mechanism. I was about to retag when I noticed you removed the tag.

Comment: There's no feature here, @Sha. The Markdown diff shows changes to text, which is what's asked for; the HTML diff shows changes to the rendered HTML, which is useful in some situations as well (but not this one).